# Interface to fit on camera view on Scene Kit

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am using SceneKit on a game.

At a certain point I need to show a menu. The menu has a background, buttons and texts, as expected from a menu.

Suppose this menu was created using UIKit. If that was the case, the background image would have lead/trailing/top/bottom constraints to glue each side to a side of the screen. How do I do that using SceneKit? I want the background to attach to the four sides of the screen, independently of the screen size (iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+).

To easy things, the camera is orthographic when the menu shows. I guess the method would involve positioning the camera so, its sides fit the background polygon. Or if not possible a way to calculate the size a plane that is on a certain x,y,z, must have to be completely filling the screen.

Everything must be done with SceneKit. No UIKit.

Is there a way to do that?

NOTE: The whole menu is created in SceneKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCNView displaying your SCNScene is a subclass of UIView. Therefore you can use four constraints to attach each side of your menu to the sides of SCNView, and use the constant property of a constraint to animate the view in and out. Simply add the menu view to the SCNView's superview and it will display over the scene.

Comment: I am not sure if my question is clear enough. I think it is not because your answer seems to imply that the menu is UIKit. I am adding the information to the question that the menu is all created in SceneKit. Is your answer valid in that case? thanks and sorry if the question misled you.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put in the menu view. It can be another SCNView with your custom controls, or a standard interface built with UIKit. Andy's approach works either way. You might consider, though, using SCNView's overlaySKScene and do the interface in SpriteKit. You'll likely see better framerates that way.

Comment: the solution doesn't solve the problem for one reason: the technique shows how to center a view on the window but not how to center the objects on a view.

Comment: Your question didn't mention that detail. Those are really two different problems. Can you post a new question with a playground containing an MCVE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve